# How to make a general profile for PHPUnit testing in WebIDE?

Tags: phpunit, web-ide

I'm playing a bit with beta version of [PHP Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webide/) (PHP version of WebIDE) and its integration of PHPUnit. I know how to set a profile to run tests in particular file, directory or class. Problem is, I'd like to create some profile where Run button would run tests in **currently opened file**.

Any idea if there's a way to do it? Or perhaps it isn't implemented in beta version yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a context run/debug menu via *Ctrl-Alt-F9* (this depends on your OS, look at *Run|Debug...* menu item), then look at lines marked with *2* & *3* - they correspond to current file and test. Press number to invoke.

You can record a macro with *Tools|Record Macro* and add a shortcut via *Settings|Keymap|Macros*. Do not forget to make a *Copy* on default keymap before attempting a change.